# Error: 400: Your project does not own Dynamic Links domain

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm using react-native-firebase to create dynamic links, when I create standard link everything works fine, but when I'm creating short link, it gives an error:

> "Error: 400: Your project does not own Dynamic Links domain".

Any ideas how is possible to fix that?

UPDATE: problem occurs **only in Android**, in IOS works fine

Code for the creating short dynamic link:

```js
onClickShare= () => {
const link =
    new firebase.links.DynamicLink(redirectLink , Config.FIREBASE_CONFIG.dynamicLink)
      .android.setPackageName(Config.ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME)
      .ios.setBundleId(Config.IOS_BUNDLE_ID)
      .ios.setAppStoreId(Config.IOS_APP_STORE_ID)
      .social.setDescriptionText(description)
      .social.setTitle(this.props.event.title)

      firebase.links()
      .createShortDynamicLink(link, 'SHORT')
      .then((url) => {
      Share.share({
        message: _('shareLinkMessage') + " " + url,
        title: _('shareLinkTitle'),
       }, {
        // Android only:
        dialogTitle:  _('shareLinkAndroid'),
        })
      })
```

Comment: This github issue seems to point to an application ID mismatch: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/393

Comment: @Cory I saw this, but my app has the same application ID, which I'm using in my app

Comment: @Lucky_girl Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Tometoyou but I think that problem can be in google-services.json file, I would recommend you to update it, and see if it will solve the problem!

Comment: Yes it was that! Thanks :)

Comment: @Tometoyou awesome, happy that it works! Please vote for the answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you get such error, update your `google-services.json` file!

Comment: how to update this file ? I only download it from Firebase there is no option to update it

Answer (score 1):

In my case (using Flutter), I was getting this error because of incorrect "uriPrefix" parameter while in DynamicLinkParameters object params:

```
final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: your_page_link, //<-- this should be same as in your Firebase project
      link: Uri.parse(....),
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        ....
      ),
      iosParameters: IOSParameters(
        ....
      ),
    );
```

Please make sure if you have uriPrefix value set properly.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your link URL

```
https://yourDomain?WXYZ?d=1
```

To

```
https://yourDomain/WXYZ?d=1 

As per allowed URL 
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this method,

import dynamicLinks from '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links';

async function generateLink() {
const link = await dynamicLinks().buildLink({
link: 'valid domain url',
domainUriPrefix: 'valid domain url',
analytics: {
  content: 'your data',
},
});
console.log(link)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

when you get this error that means you did not add the dynamic link domain as a formate of the firebase link.

you must follow this formate:
<app_name.page.link>

In android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml add within the activity:

```
<!-- Deep linking -->
<meta-data android:name='flutter _deeplinking_enabled' 
android:value="true" />
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="<app_name.page.link>" />
<data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

and added at the same with that formate <app_name.page.link> in dynamic link code.

Answer (score -3):

You might not have done npm install if your google-services.json is already updated